# Wie einer neuen Beziehung viel Glück wünschen?

Tags: salutation

Wenn zwei Personen eine Beziehung eingehen, ist es ja üblich, ihnen viel Glück zu wünschen. Das finde ich aber unpassend, da dies sarkastisch rüberkommen kann.

Was gibt es denn da für Alternativen?

Comment: Bitte Englisch oder Deutsch als Fragensprache nehmen - keine SMS-Kürzel wie 'irg wie' oder 'net', und kein Dialekt ('jibbet'). Fragen zu Dialekt sind zwar willkommen, aber Personen, deren Muttersprache nicht Deutsch ist, sollten mit Hilfe eines ordinären Wörterbuchs die Frage verstehen können.

Comment: Ich wollte erst was anwtworten zu Glück (Spielglück, Zufall) vs. Glück (das Gefühl) - aber eigentlich weiß ich ja gar nicht, welche Art Glück Du meinst. Einem Paar das gemeinsame Glücksgefühl zu wünschen, finde ich jetzt gar nicht unpassend. Welche Bedeutung von Glück meinst Du?

Comment: Ja, das is auch wieder so ne Sache das kann ich auch net ganz eindeutig sagen wer das wie meint.
Und mit Glück(als Gefühl) meinst du wohl Glücklichkeit?!
(weil mann ja auch spüren kann wenn mann "Spielglück" hat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wenn 2 Personen eine Beziehung eingehen ist es ja üblich denen viel Glück zu wünschen

Ich glaube, da geht es letztendlich darum, was der Begriff "Glück" im Deutschen heißt: einmal ein Zustand von Zufriedenheit (z. B. "Mutterglück") und zum anderen ein günstiger Zufall ("Glück beim Kartenspiel").

Ich würde jemandem in dieser Situation nicht "Viel Glück!" wünschen, denn das kann leicht sarkastisch rüberkommen, im Sinne von: Das, was ihr da gemeinsam vorhabt, hat wenig Aussicht auf Erfolg, also kann ich euch nur Glück wünschen.

Besser ist es da, eine Formulierung zu verwenden, die dieses Missverständnis ausschließt:

> "Ich wünsche euch, dass ihr einander glücklich macht"
>
> "Hoffentlich seht ihr einer glücklichen [gemeinsamen] Zeit entgegen"

Es spricht aber auch nichts dagegen, ganz allgemein "alles Gute" oder Ähnliches zu wünschen, finde ich.

Comment: Genau das was du im 2. Absatz geschrieben hast meinte ich,
wusst nur net wie ich das ausdrückn sollte.

Answer (score 2):

Wünsche ihnen eine "glückliche Partnerschaft/Beziehung" statt "Glück in der Partnerschaft/Beziehung" ...

Glücklich sein hat ja nichts mit Glück in dem zu vermeidenden Zusammenhang ("positiver Zufall") zu tun.